# has_many through return multiple associated objects in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have a problem with has_many through association in Rails .
Have model :

```
class Interval < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :training

 has_many :termins
 has_many :users, through: :termins
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :role
 has_many :termins
 has_many :intervals, through: :termins
end

class Termin < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :interval
 belongs_to :user
end
```

So, I have created an interval for one user, and created few termins:

```
Interval.first #=> <Interval id: 6, from: "2014-10-17", to: "2014-11-17", training_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-16 22:39:38", updated_at: "2014-10-16 22:39:38">

Interval.first.termins 
[
  #<Termin id: 9, interval_id: 6, user_id: 4, term: "2014-10-16", created_at: "2014-10-16 22:42:15", updated_at: "2014-10-16 22:42:15">,
  #<Termin id: 10, interval_id: 6, user_id: 4, term: "2014-10-23", created_at: "2014-10-16 22:43:02", updated_at: "2014-10-16 22:43:02">,
  #<Termin id: 11, interval_id: 6, user_id: 4, term: "2014-10-31", created_at: "2014-10-16 22:44:40", updated_at: "2014-10-16 22:44:40">
]
```

But, when I put :
Interval.first.users

```
[
 #<User id: 4, email: "member@gym.com", encrypted_password:    "$2a$10$ChVTiXt2EjKzKYiq4GEvT.d21MuOHydJxCGxDextAYt0...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-10-15 22:27:44", updated_at: "2014-10-16 21:21:25", first_name: "Member", last_name: "Member", phone_number: "00000000", date_of_birth: "1989-10-16", sex: "0", role_id: 3>,
 #<User id: 4, email: "member@gym.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$ChVTiXt2EjKzKYiq4GEvT.d21MuOHydJxCGxDextAYt0...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-10-15 22:27:44", updated_at: "2014-10-16 21:21:25", first_name: "Member", last_name: "Member", phone_number: "00000000", date_of_birth: "1989-10-16", sex: "0", role_id: 3>,
 #<User id: 4, email: "member@gym.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$ChVTiXt2EjKzKYiq4GEvT.d21MuOHydJxCGxDextAYt0...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-10-15 22:27:44", updated_at: "2014-10-16 21:21:25", first_name: "Member", last_name: "Member", phone_number: "00000000", date_of_birth: "1989-10-16", sex: "0", role_id: 3>
]
```

**I want to get only 1 record for the last query because there is the same user three times.** 
Any help is welcome .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make it:

```
has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :termins
```

Before Rails 4 you would use `has_many :users, through: :termins, uniq: true` but it is now deprecated and the use of dash-rocket above is a way to go.